# Type 'string | undefined' is not > assignable to type 'string'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I just want to compare two arrays together but one of the array comes from a 3rd party AWS, which I cannot make sure that it exists.

Somehow I am not able to bypass my error.
I am protecting the call of the function by returning and I still get this error:

> Argument of type '(string | undefined)[]' is not assignable to
> parameter of type 'string[]'.   Type 'string | undefined' is not
> assignable to type 'string'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)

I'm also getting a warning trying to check the both arrays match.

```
const fileNames = files?.Contents?.filter((content) => content.Key?.endsWith('.docx')).map((content) =>
  content.Key?.replace(FOLDER_PATH, '')
);

if (!fileNames || !fileNames.length || fileNames === undefined) {
  return;
}

compareFileNames(fileNames, configFiles) // compilation error above


// ...


const compareFileNames = (a: string[], b: string[]) => {
  if (a.length !== b.length) return false;
  return a.sort().toString() === b.sort().toString(); // Warning Move this array "sort" operation to a separate statement

}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MAUATAhlLAuGaAJwEswBzAbQF0BKFAPhgG8BYAKBi5iIFMoArkTAwA5AAleAGylIA6iCJSMogNwcAvhw6hIsALZYyKdPWRM27Dtxi7oMbLgICwGXnDK8MNE5RduPMC9qdStObhI4NABCRywYAB8EmCgATwAHXhA4Bxx45AKxf3dPFUTktMzs3NxKAAZqFELRYsCvUXpLGxs+QWFQmy0wmwQQTDzaUKGOQzI0SaA)

What are the problems here?

Answer (score 0):

In your example you write:

```
if(!data || typeof data === 'undefined' || typeof data[0] === 'undefined') {
    return;
}
```

which can be shortened to:

```
if(data.some(item => item === undefined)) {
    return;
}
```

Next, you're passing `data` to a method that only accepts `string[]` but `data` still has the type `Array<string | undefined>` because typescript cannot infer that there are no `undefined` elements inside of the array based on the if condition.

You can either cast the array to a `string[]` manually, or use a typeguard:

Cast:

```
const main = () => {
    const data: Array<string | undefined> = [undefined];
    if(data.some(item => item === undefined)) {
        return;
    }
    foo(data as Array<string>);
}
```

Typeguard:

```
const main = () => {
    const data: Array<string | undefined> = [undefined];
    if(!isNotUndefinedArray(data)) {
        return;
    }
    foo(data);
}

function isNotUndefinedArray<T>(a_arr: Array<T | undefined>): a_arr is Array<T> {
    return !a_arr.some(a_item => a_item === undefined);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The expression
`.map((content) => content.Key?.replace(FOLDER_PATH, ''))`
returns either a string or undefined. Therefor the inferred type of `fileNames` is `(string | undefined)[]`.

You can change your statement to this

```
const fileNames: string[] = files?.Contents?
.filter((content) => content.Key?.endsWith('.docx'))
.map((content) =>
  content.Key?.replace(FOLDER_PATH, '')
)
.filter( s => s);
```

The last `filter` removes all undefined entries.

Comment: That doesn't look good. Why the if clause doesn't work??

Comment: What do you mean by "the if clause doesn't work'? . I tried to show you how to fix "Argument of type '(string | undefined)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string[]'."

Comment: I'm trying to return if the array is undefined or is empty, why it gives error after the if???

Comment: What error does it give? And which of the both "if" do you mean? You are not returning the result of compareFileNames(...). Is this intentional?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MAUATAhlLAuGaAJwEswBzAbQF0BKFAPhgG8BYAKBi5iIFMoArkTAwA5AAleAGylIA6iCJSMogNwcAvhw6hIsALZYyKdPWRM27Dtxi7oMbLgICwGXnDK8MNE5RduPMC9qdStObhI4NABCRywYAB8EmCgATwAHXhA4Bxx45AKxf3dPFUTktMzs3NxKAAZqFELRYsCvUXpLGxs+QWFQmy0wmwQQTDzaUKGOQzI0SaA